# Is it possible to create a database, user, password using php and a form (with only cpanel, no WHM)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I can connect but not create the database. 
[Connected to Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap69W.png)

```
 <body>
   <?php
    //Database Connection Variables

     $servername = "localhost";
     $username = "******";
     $password = "********";
     $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
    //The Connection and test
     if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
     }
     echo "Connected successfully";
     //If the form is submitted create the database
     if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
     $dbname = $_POST['dbname']; 
     $user = $_POST['user'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
     $sql = "CREATE DATABASE $dbname";
     $sql = "CREATE USER $user";
     $sql = "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $dbname.* To '$user' IDENTIFIED BY '$password'";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE) {
    echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
    }
    }
    ?>

   <div class="container">

   <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
   <div class="row">

   <div class="col-25">
     <label for="dbname">New DB Name: </label>
   </div>

   <div class="col-75">
     <input type="text" name="dbname" placeholder="Enter New Database Name">

  </div>


  <div class="col-25">
     <label for="user">New User Name: </label>
   </div>

   <div class="col-75">
     <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Enter New User Name">

  </div>


<div class="col-25">
     <label for="password">New Password: </label>
   </div>

   <div class="col-75">
     <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Enter New Password">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="GO" />
  </div>

  </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```

The issue (I think) is I only have cpanel and do not have WHM so I do not have a root mySQL password. I want to do this all via a form, create database, users, passwords, tables, upload data, etc.

The goal is to have an end user with no technical skills be able to create, view, add data in a marketing database via a form.

Comment: You are only executing the `GRANT` as all 3 statements use `$sql` and only the last one is executed.

Comment: use multi query `mysqli::multi_query`

Comment: as per question, i think no, it will check your database user when execute the query, and it will your permission, if you permission of these queries, you can do it. if your user having rights, then its possible

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out **not** having a WHM root sql password is limiting. Using only cPanel this works. but you must have the xmlapi.php loaded on your server [link below].

```
<body>
<?php
//Database Connection Variables

 include("xmlapi.php"); //your need to have this on the server same folder 

 $db_host = 'yourdomain.com'; //your URL
 $cpaneluser = 'yourcpaneluser'; // the user you use to sign into cpanel
 $cpanelpass = 'yourcpanelpassword'; // the cpanel user password
 ///If the form is submitted create the database
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 $databasename = $_POST['dbname']; 
 $databaseuser = $_POST['user'];
 $databasepass = $_POST['password'];}
 $xmlapi = new xmlapi($db_host);    
 $xmlapi->password_auth("".$cpaneluser."","".$cpanelpass."");    
 $xmlapi->set_port(2082);
 $xmlapi->set_debug(1);//output actions in the error log 1 for true and 0 false  
 $xmlapi->set_output('array');//set this for browser output  
 //create database    
 $createdb = $xmlapi->api1_query($cpaneluser, "Mysql", "adddb", 
 array($databasename));   
 //create user 
 $usr = $xmlapi->api1_query($cpaneluser, "Mysql", "adduser", array($databaseuser,      
 $databasepass));   
 //add user 
 $addusr = $xmlapi->api1_query($cpaneluser, "Mysql", "adduserdb", 
 array("".$cpaneluser."_".     $databasename."", "".$cpaneluser."_".$databaseuser."", 
 'all'));
 ?>




<div class="container">
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<div class="row">

   <div class="col-25">
     <label for="dbname">New DB Name: </label>
   </div>
<div class="col-75">
     <input type="text" name="dbname" placeholder="Enter New Database Name">
</div>


  <div class="col-25">
     <label for="user">New User Name: </label>
   </div>

   <div class="col-75">
     <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Enter New User Name">

  </div>


<div class="col-25">
     <label for="password">New Password: </label>
   </div>

   <div class="col-75">
     <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Enter New Password">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="GO" />
  </div>

  </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```

You can download the xmlapi here https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php/blob/master/xmlapi.php